# given an EPR pair, how do I calculate expectation value?

Tags: mathematics, measurement, experimental-realization, bell-experiment

given A and B share EPR pairs $ (|00⟩+|11⟩)/√2$

both are free to measure their own qubit with the following measurement settings

A measures with $[ |0⟩, |1⟩ ]$

B measures with $[ sin(3π/8)|0⟩ + cos(3π/8)|1⟩, -sin(π/8)|0⟩ + cos(π/8)|1⟩]$

Comment: Hi @MarkS, I am trying to know what will be the value when A measures in [|0⟩,|1⟩]  basis or bell basis

Comment: I am new to quantum computing, please correct me if I am not clear enough

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the 4 probabilities in each case, or are you asking how to calculate an expectation value (which is what your question actually says)? If the latter, what expectation value are you wanting to calculate? That would be some function of the measurement outcomes that you want the average of.

Answer (score 1):

The key to figuring out the probability of any measurement result is Born's rule, which says that if you have a state $\left|\psi\right\rangle$ the probability of observing measurement outcome $\left|\phi\right\rangle$ is given by
$$
\begin{align}
    \Pr(\phi | \psi) = \left|\left\langle \phi | \psi \right\rangle \right|^2.
\end{align}
$$
In the example you described, let's consider the probability with which Alice observes $\left|0\right\rangle$ and Bob observes $\sin(3\pi / 8) \left| 0\right\rangle + \cos(3\pi / 8) \left| 1\right\rangle$. This outcome occurs with probability
$$
\begin{align}
     & \Pr(A=0,B=0|\text{EPR}) \\
     & \quad = \frac12\left|
         \sin(3\pi / 8) \left\langle 00 | 00 \right\rangle +
         \cos(3\pi / 8) \left\langle 01 | 00 \right\rangle +
         \sin(3\pi / 8) \left\langle 00 | 11 \right\rangle +
         \cos(3\pi / 8) \left\langle 01 | 11 \right\rangle
     \right|^2 \\
     & \quad = \frac12\left|
         \sin(3\pi / 8)
     \right|^2 \approx 0.85.
\end{align}
$$
Here, we used that the four computational basis states $\left\{\left|00\right\rangle, \left|01\right\rangle, \left|10\right\rangle, \left|11\right\rangle \right\}$ are all orthogonal to each other, so that the $\left\langle 00 | 00\right\rangle$ is the only one that survives.

The probability for each of the other three outcomes can be worked out in a similar fashion using Born's rule.

Comment: thank you Chris, can you also explain to me how to calculate the expectation value when Alice observes $|0⟩$ and Bob observes $sin(3π/8)|0⟩+cos(3π/8)|1⟩$